# The time zone ID 'Pacific Standard Time' was not found on the local computer

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timezone

I have deployed my application on AWS Lambda but while getting time zone i am getting this error

```
'The time zone ID 'Pacific Standard Time' was not found on the local computer.'
```

How can i add timezones on lambda.

```
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(userModel.TimeZoneListCode);
```

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? "Pacific Standard Time" is a Windows time zone database ID; the corresponding IANA one would be America/Los_Angeles. I would generally encourage you to use IANA IDs everywhere, but in .NET 6 you should be able to use either style on every platform.

Comment: @JonSkeet The TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(string) method automatically accepts either Windows or IANA time zones on either platform and converts them if needed.

Comment: Yes, it does *in .NET 6*. It doesn't in older versions, which is why I was asking what version of .NET you're using. If you're using .NET Core 3.1, that would explain the problem, for example.

Comment: Also, the conversions in .NET 6 only work if ICU data is available (either pre-installed, or app-local ICU).  I'm not sure if AWS Lambda has ICU or not, TBH.  If not, you can use `America/Los_Angeles`, or if necessary you can do the conversions with [timezoneconverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, if Windows time zones like this don't work:

```cs
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
```

... then you're not running on Windows *and* either you're not using .NET 6 or higher, or you don't have ICU data available in your environment.  Either way, you should be able to use IANA time zones:

```cs
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Alternatively, you can use [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) to work with either form:

```cs
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Pacific Standard Time");
```

or

```cs
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: As an FYI for anyone experiencing an issue like this on Windows Server 2019 or later, it looks like you must have .NET 7 or higher in order for the ICU data to be available by default: [ICU on Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/globalization/7.0/icu-globalization-api). Or you could build your app with the app-local ICU option.